# Is there a website where I can just post my HTML/CSS and see the result?

Tags: html, css, web

While developing a mobile Application I tend to see error messages on my console. These are sended from a server and are meant to be seen in a browser.

However it is really hard to inpret these if you see the HTML and CSS. I would love to just find a website where I can just put the Code and see the formatted result. Does there exist a website like that?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ also a good option

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ does run JS/CSS/HTML, it doesn't emulate mobile devices if that's what you're after?

Though its pasted/typed input, so it won't... read from your App either...

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will show the page in whichever browser you view that site in. You could also [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) which allows you to get screenshots in different browsers - although currenlty there are no mobile browsers.

Comment: True that, forgot about those sites - browsercam.com does device capture but it isn't free, you can have a 24-hour trial though.